# Flutter dont reload a image when i take a picture

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

i'm studying flutter and im trying to create a person register. In this page i hava a normal register with basic data and person photo.

But im having some issue with update a Image, when i take the picture the component Image dont change to taked image;
I tried find some controller to Image or Image Provider but unsuccessful. 
This is my code:

```
class _RegisterForm extends State<RegisterForm> {
  final TextEditingController _textEditingControllerPassword =
      new TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController _textEditingControllerComparePassword =
      new TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController _textEditingControllerEmail =
      new TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController _textEditingControllerFullName =
      new TextEditingController();

  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  User _user = null;
  Image _image = null;

  @override
  void setState(VoidCallback fn) {
    super.initState();
    this._user = new User(
      _textEditingControllerPassword.text,
      _textEditingControllerFullName.text,
      _textEditingControllerEmail.text,
      _textEditingControllerComparePassword.text,
      _image,
    );
    this.build(context);
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Form(
        key: _formKey,
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(23, 0, 23, 0),
          child: Column(children: <Widget>[
            GestureDetector(
              child: CircleAvatarImage(_image),
              onTap: getImage,
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: Text("Tire sua foto!"),
            ),
            InputString(
              "Como gostaria ",
              hint: "Marianx Silva",
              maxLenght: 100,
              controller: this._textEditingControllerFullName,
              onChanged: (context) => {
                setState(() {
                  _user = null;
                }),
              },
            ),
            InputString(
              "E-mail",
              maxLenght: 100,
              controller: this._textEditingControllerEmail,
              onChanged: (context) => {
                setState(() {
                  _user = null;
                }),
              },
            ),
            InputString(
              "Senha",
              controller: this._textEditingControllerPassword,
              maxLenght: 12,
              obscureText: true,
              onChanged: (context) => {
                setState(() {
                  _user = null;
                }),
              },
            ),
            InputString(
              "Confime a senha",
              controller: this._textEditingControllerComparePassword,
              maxLenght: 12,
              obscureText: true,
              onChanged: (context) => {
                setState(() {
                  _user = null;
                }),
              },
            ),
            RegisterUserInFirebaseButton(
              "Continuar",
              _formKey,
              _user,
//              edgeInsets: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 40, 0, 0),
            ),
          ]),
        ));
  }

  Future getImage() async {
    File image = await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.camera);
    this._image = Image.file(image);
    setState(() {
      _user = null;
    });
  }
}
```

This is my "CircleAvatarImage" component:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

const AssetImage _defaultImage = AssetImage("assets/images/default_image.png");


class CircleAvatarImage extends StatefulWidget {
  Image image;

  CircleAvatarImage(this.image);

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return __CircleAvatarImageState();
  }
}

class __CircleAvatarImageState extends State<CircleAvatarImage> {
  AnimationController _controller;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CircleAvatar(
      radius: 62,
      backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
      child: CircleAvatar(
        radius: 60.0,
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 90),
          child: Icon(
            Icons.camera_enhance,
            color: Colors.white,
          ),
        ),
        backgroundImage:
        widget.image == null ? _defaultImage : widget.image.image,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: where is the implementation of CircleAvatarImage() ?

Comment: what is `CircleAvatarImage` widget ? is it a custom widget you are using?

Comment: @VickySalunkhe i add the code of CircleAvatarImage

Answer (score 0):

You didn't use setState. So, there's no way Widget would no that it has to udpate. Try :

```
setState() => this._image = Image.file(image);
```

Comment: He is calling setstate in the very next line of that, so I think that's not issue.

Comment: Right! But setstate doesn't include `_image`. It is just setting user to null.

Comment: I will setstate every variables which change its value.

Comment: Okay. Perhaps my understanding on setState is wrong. I'll check. Thanks.

Comment: So, i tried your approach but the image didn't change either. :/

Comment: I descoverd the problems. The problems it is i dont set inte the setState the super.setState....

Comment: Glad you solve the problem. Please post the answer as an answer and mark it as accepted so that the next user will get to the solution immediately.